# comparing elements of two lists with adding exception for the second list?

Tags: python

I need to compare the elements of two lists regardless of the order or the position. I know that question has been asked a lot. but I have an exception for the second list to exclude an element in a for loop. A piece of code is shown:

```
 s = [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
 c=  [2,6,7,8,9]
   
     if s in (c - v):
     print ("%s is a root "%v)
     # I'm expecting here  when 7 is excluded from c all the elements of c are there in S and the condition is true
```

This code throws an error:

```
  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

In this code, c,s are two lists and v is int.

hence, my problem is how to exclude this element from the list. I know that the size of **c** is less than the size of **s**, but actually, **c** is my reference and the size of **s** is variable it could be more or less, In other words, I'm searching for the elements of **s**  in  **c** regardless of the size.

any help will be very appreciated?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The main thing I want to know is, are all the elements of `c` hashable? If so, it will probably be better to use a `set`. But also the input and expected output are important.

Comment: `if s != v and s in c`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question with a complete example

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `c - v` to *mean*?

Comment: Create a new list comprehension on the fly: `if s in [x for x in x if x != c]`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I was assuming it meant "all elements in `c`, except for `v`".

Comment: yes exactly this is what I meant by @KarlKnechtel

Comment: @Amedeo It's still not complete because it's missing the expected output. Also it would help if you made it simpler by removing the dependency on networkx.

Comment: elements of s in c means [2, 6, 8, 9]?

Comment: yes, thank you for your reply @adamkwm. I don't understand what s != v means here

Comment: you don't define v and have no s != v in your code, what is v?

Comment: it was 7 in my old edit

Comment: Then it just means [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9] != 7 and it's True.

Comment: I've just read your comment in your code, you want to get the excluded value (v) so when v is exclude from c, all elements in c are in s? Can v be more than one values?

Comment: no v always one value. but when I write the condition like this, it is not True. 
s != v and s in c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224821/discussion-between-adamkwm-and-amedeo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All thanks to @adamkwm, he guided me through the answer and clarification.
Here is exactly what I want:

```
  s = [0, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
  c = [2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  x = set(c) - (set(s) & set(c))
  for v in x:
      print(v)
```

Comment: I tried it once again, `x = set(c) - set(s)` is already ok, the & part is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx

edges = [(1, 0),(1, 4),(1, 6),(1, 8),(0, 3),(0, 4),(0, 5),(0, 7),
    (0, 9),(2, 5),(2, 7),(3, 4),(3, 8),(3, 9),(4, 6),
    (4, 8),(4, 9),(5, 6),(5, 7),(5, 8),(6, 7),(6, 8),(6, 9),(7, 8),(7,9)]

k= nx.Graph()
k.add_edges_from(edges)

c= [2,6,7,8,9]

for v in c:
    s = list(k.neighbors(v))
    if s != v and s in c:
        print ("%s is a root "%v)
```

And the result is nothing.
Is this what you want?

Comment: Actually, I'm expecting element 7 to be an answer, but I have discovered now that S has more elements than C in this case, and hence the condition is false also. I would like to account for both cases if S in C  or C in S

Comment: can I write:
                   if s != v and s in c or  if c != v and c in s: